# How to properly check in DLLs/assemblies to TFS/Visual Studio Team Services (was VSO)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

We have several DLLs referenced by a project that are not available through NuGet. Every time one has to copy the DLL file across after pulling the solution from TFS/VSTS, which is quite tedious and confusing for ppl not familiar with our projects.

Is there a way to properly check the DLLs in to TFS/VSTS? Obviously we can include the BIN folder in the solution but is that the right thing to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In some scenarios it's useful to have a folder named "libs", or "libraries", for example, that contains all the assemblies required by your projects to compile and run. So you can check-in this folder. In each project you need to reference the dll contained here (Visual Studio automatically save the path using relative path).
Include the "bin" folder is not the right way, because if a developer performs a "Clean solution" in Visual Studio, it clean this folder.

Answer (score 7):

### **Getting DLL's Into Visual Studio Team Services in Two Steps**

I'm not sure how to do it in TFS, but with Visual Studio Team Services (Visual Studio Online) do the following...

### Step 1

In VSTS navigate to where the files should be located in the Code area of your project.

[image: Navigate to the Code area of your project]

### Step 2:

Simply click the upload files button and select the .dll or other files types you want to add to your repository.

[image: Upload Button]

Now when you get or refresh the project your .dll files will be included as well.

---

It would be nice to be able to do this directly from Visual Studio, unfortunately I'm am not aware of how to do this.

Comment: One thing I failed to mention is that for some files, like dll's and pdb's, you may get an, "Unable to perform the get operation because the file already exists locally" warning. In other words if you have a newer version of a dll then you may have to delete it off of your local folder and retry the get to have the latest version downloaded. So watch out for that.

Comment: Drag and drop of the folder containing the dll(s) from Windows Explorer to the Source Control Explorer window in VS worked fine for me.

Comment: @BH Were you able to check those in and have them copy up to Visual Studio online? I'm able to get them in VS just fine, but when I check in the project from Visual Studio 2017 it seems to ignore any .dll or .exe files.

Answer (score 4):

I was also having issues with check-in dlls from package folder into TFS. Everything from packages folder was getting checked-in except dlls.
if someone still having this issue then you should read this article [Here](https://tech.trailmax.info/2014/01/check-in-nuget-packages-into-your-tfs/)

Basically, you have let TFS know that you are okay to check-in executable,dlls files in TFS.
Steps to do this:

1. In Visual studio go to Team --> Team Project Collection settings --> Source Control
2. 'File types' tab --> make sure **Executable Files** [image: See screenshot]
3. Go to source control explorer
4. Go to folder from where you want to add dll (in my case, packages folder)
5. Right click the folder --> Add item to folder --> locate the folder of dll with the help of 'Next' button --> select/(highlight) the dlls  --> click on 'include item(s)' --> click on 'Finish'
6. Repeat step 5 for other dlls if any
7. Last but not least, check-in the above included dlls from your code to TFS

Answer (score 2):

The simple way is that:

1. Put assembly files in the folder under the team project or your solution folder level.
2. Map the necessary assemblies to the local machine according to your solution/project, for example D:\Lib[assembly files], D:[solution folder][Project folder]
3. Reference these assembly by right click the reference folder of project and browser to these assemblies files and add
4. Check the file path in project file (e.g. csproj), the code likes ....\Lib\XXX.cs
5. For build, in Source Settings (XAML, Build Agent Folder)/Repository Mappint (VNext, LocalPath), keep the similar structure

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve with very simple spates. Add one folder called **Assemblies** inside your parent folder.

```
Development (parent folder)
          --->Your Code (child folder)
          --->Assemblies (child folder)
```

Add all your 3rd part dlls into assemblies folder

Now open your **.csproj** file and update reference path

`<HintPath>..\..\Assemblies\your dll file.dll</HintPath>`

Now check in your code to VSTS.

It will compile successfully...

Answer (score 0):

In my ASP MVC project I looked up into my .gitignore file, where I found this:

```
###################
# compiled source #
###################
*.com
*.class
*.dll
*.exe
*.pdb
*.dll.config
*.cache
*.suo
# Include dlls if they’re in the NuGet packages directory
!*/packages/*/lib/*.dll
!*/packages/*/lib/*/*.dll
# Include dlls if they're in the CommonReferences directory
!*/CommonReferences/*.dll
```

In this case, the correct folder for 3rd party `.dll`s would be `CommonReferences`.