# Azure Devops - Interop Libraries

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, office-interop, azure-pipelines-build-task

Currently through Azure Devops, I'm setting up a .Net Desktop type with pipe-line that includes assembly libraries. In my understanding this should've work if the scenario was TFS is on-premise and I can just install any 3rd party non-nuget libraries in that server and make the build work. Right now I was able to make this work by literally copying the .dlls but I felt its more of a hack than actually letting the build know that I'm referencing assembly / non-nuget package libraries.

I'm pretty sure i've missed something, is there a way to properly set this up?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though it's not a recommend way, but you could check in these libraries/dlls in source control.  TFS could download them from server to your build agent and refer them.

First, make sure your local build is successful and if just the TFS build is failing then it is usually due to dll reference path issue. Make sure that the Dll is referenced as a **relative path** in the project file (.csproj).

To add a relative reference in a separate directory, such as C:\tfs_get\Sources\assembly\abc.dll, do the following:

Add the reference in Visual Studio by right clicking the project in Solution Explorer and selecting Add Reference.

Find the *.csproj where this reference exist and open it in a text editor. Lets say your .csproj location is c:\tfs_get\sources\myfolder\myproject\myproj.csproj

Edit the < HintPath > to be equal to

```
..\\..\assembly\abc.dll
```

This build will work properly with the assumption that the folders ( assembly, myfolder) under the  sources folder exist in TFS.

---

**Update**

Have a folder named "libs", or "libraries", for example, that contains all the assemblies required by your projects to compile and run.

Reference these assembly by right click the reference folder of project and browser to these assemblies files.

For build, in Source Settings (XAML, Build Agent Folder)/Repository, keep the similar structure.

More details please take a look at this similar question : [How to properly check in DLLs/assemblies to TFS/Visual Studio Team Services (was VSO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38448178/how-to-properly-check-in-dlls-assemblies-to-tfs-visual-studio-team-services-was)

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for the answer. That's actually my default setup and I believe what you're referring to is TFS approach. My apologies but i'm working in AzureDevops (free).

Comment: @kenlacoste Seems you are talking about Azure DevOps Service url `https://dev.azure.com/xxx`. If so, instead of copying dlls, you could also directly check in them and refer them as a relative path in your project. It's the same as on-premise TFS server. The  main difference for **build agent** in Azure DevOps Service and TFS on-premise is one is not able to access (host agent) which manage by cloud, one is able to access and remote to manage by yourself. Besides, for Azure DevOps Service you could also use self-host agent.

Comment: @kenlacoste Of course, the recommend way is using Nuget/Feed to manage these libraries in Azure DevOps Service. You could package and publish these 3rd party  libraries to your private feed in Azure DevOps Service, about this part, kindly refer this link: [Get started with private NuGet feeds in Azure DevOps Service](https://medium.com/@ginomessmer/get-started-with-private-nuget-feeds-in-azure-devops-8c7b5f022a68)

Comment: not sure how to package ReportViewer redistributable, OracleDb libraries and Microsoft.Interop for MS office interop activities. Can you point me how to make them nuget?

Comment: Hi Ken lacoste, sorry for the later reply due to miss prompting message. For this kind of dlls  that are not available through NuGet. You should directly check them in  source control. Have a folder named "libs", or "libraries", for example, that contains all the assemblies required by your projects to compile and run. Kindly refer this similar link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38448178/how-to-properly-check-in-dlls-assemblies-to-tfs-visual-studio-team-services-was  Also updated my reply.

Comment: sure, no worries. Again I can't check in this .dlls because these are GAC installed like ReportViewer and OracleDb. I wonder how to get around this types.

Comment: @kenlacoste Hi, sorry not get your point, you said `Right now I was able to make this work by literally copying the .dlls` if you should be able to copy these dlls from GAC, you should also be able to check these dlls in source control. Then download the dlls in build agent and refer them during build. But we just not totally confirm if these dlls could work outside of GAC during your reference, since these dlls have installed with software or Dbserver.

Comment: With all that said, you should keep your build agent/server environment the same with your local environment. Please double check this. Such as remote to the build agent and manually build in remote succeed. This is related to environment not TFS side. After all, tfs is  also just calling vs or ms build command to run the build. If you build locally on remote build agent/server failed, you will  definitely get a failed TFS build result.

Comment: Yup I did make the build work already even before this post. Sure I guess for .dlls that are non-nuget this is pretty wishful thinking, its like expecting azure (free) to have all GAC installed .dlls available. I don't have a local environment unfortunately but I do understand the setup you're describing. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @kenlacoste Thanks for your kindly response. Yes, as you have pointed out `its like expecting azure (free) to have all GAC installed .dlls available`  It' not  installed on MSFT hosted build agent, we do have a list show all software dlls which already installed in the image. You could find the info here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops#use-a-microsoft-hosted-agent  By the way if the information provided was helpful or gave a right direction. Appreciate for marking it as an answer which will also helps others in the community.